# Median and 95th percentile in SQL server 2008? - NHS reports requirement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, function, aggregate

I have tried to find out 95th percentile and median build in function in SQL server 2008 but I do not know why MS does not give support for them, really annoying... Our work place reports are very complex and wanted a straight forward function or may be a dll file which i could assemble with SQL server to use it as normal function.

could any one advice. Thanks in advance.

Reagrds
Ali

Answer (score 1):

There's [NTILE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175126.aspx) function and for MEDIAN read [this](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/adam_machanic/archive/2006/12/18/medians-row-numbers-and-performance.aspx).

Comment: Cheers Mladen Prajdic! I will be looking into this function and article, but if some one could help find a dynamic link libraby ( dll ) to assemble it with SQL server to make these funcation as build in will be very helpful. Thanks again for your kind reply

Answer (score 0):

95 th percentile formula is 
MAX(Rownumber)*95/100

```
WITH kali1(k1, k2, k3, k4, k5, k6, k7) AS 
(
    SELECT MinsInAE,
           HoursInAE,
           DaysInAE AS DaysInAE,
           Month_Name,
           YearName,
           InternalNo,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Month_Name ORDER BY MinsInAE ASC) AS 
           'Row Number'
    FROM   AE.FactAandE
           INNER JOIN AE.PMI
                ON  AE.FactAandE.FK_PaitentMasterIndex = AE.PMI.PK_Patient
           INNER JOIN dbo.TimeDimension
                ON  dbo.TimeDimension.DateId = AE.FactAandE.FK_date
    WHERE  YearName = 'Calendar 2010'
) 
,
kali2(k21, k22, k23)
AS 
(
    SELECT MAX(k7) * 95 / 100,
           k4,
           MAX(k7)
    FROM   kali1
    GROUP BY
           k4
)
SELECT kali2.k21   AS percentilerow,
       kali2.k22   AS Month_Name,
       (kali1.k1)  AS percentilevalue
FROM   kali2
       INNER JOIN kali1
            ON  kali1.k4 = kali2.k22
WHERE  kali1.k7 = kali2.k21
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a DLL in Visual Studio to do this by creating a custom aggregate function for use in SQL Server.  To do this create a new Visual Studio project and set the target framework to .NET 3.5 (this is for SQL 2008, it may be different in SQL 2012). Then create a class file and put in the following code, or c# equivalent.

Note that this algorithm gets the nearest value to the specified percentile.  If you want to use a different percentile algorithm, then the code could be modified for that.

This process allows the user to enter any percentile to query for.  The query would look like this:  SELECT dbo.Percentile(Value, 95) FROM Table

```
Imports Microsoft.SqlServer.Server
Imports System.Data.SqlTypes
Imports System.IO

<Serializable>
<SqlUserDefinedAggregate(Format.UserDefined, IsInvariantToNulls:=True, IsInvariantToDuplicates:=False, _
  IsInvariantToOrder:=True, MaxByteSize:=-1, IsNullIfEmpty:=True)>
Public Class Percentile
  Implements IBinarySerialize
  Private _items As List(Of Decimal)
  Private _percentile As Integer

  Public Sub Init()
    _items = New List(Of Decimal)()
  End Sub

  Public Sub Accumulate(value As SqlDecimal, percentile As SqlInt32)
    _percentile = percentile
    If Not value.IsNull Then
      _items.Add(value.Value)
    End If
  End Sub

  Public Sub Merge(other As Percentile)
    _percentile = other._percentile
    If other._items IsNot Nothing Then
      _items.AddRange(other._items)
    End If
  End Sub

  Public Function Terminate() As SqlDecimal
    If _items.Count <> 0 Then
      Dim result As Decimal
      _items = _items.OrderBy(Function(i) i).ToList()

      Dim index = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round((_percentile / 100D) * _items.Count, 0))
      If (index <> 0) Then
        index -= 1
      End If
      result = _items(index)

      Return New SqlDecimal(result)
    Else
      Return New SqlDecimal()
    End If
  End Function

  Public Sub Read(r As BinaryReader) Implements IBinarySerialize.Read
    'deserialize it from a string
    Dim list = r.ReadString()

    If Not (String.IsNullOrEmpty(list)) Then
      Dim index = list.IndexOf("|"c)

      If index <> -1 Then
        _items = New List(Of Decimal)
        _percentile = Convert.ToInt32(list.Substring(0, index))
        list = list.Substring(index + 1)

        For Each value In list.Split(","c)
          Dim number As Decimal
          If Decimal.TryParse(value, number) Then
            _items.Add(number)
          End If
        Next
      End If
    End If
  End Sub

  Public Sub Write(w As BinaryWriter) Implements IBinarySerialize.Write
    'serialize the list to a string
    Dim list As String = ""

    If (_items IsNot Nothing AndAlso _items.Count > 0) Then
      list = Convert.ToString(_percentile) + "|"
      For Each item In _items
        If Not list.EndsWith("|") Then
          list += ","
        End If
        list += item.ToString("#0.0##")
      Next
    End If
    w.Write(list)
  End Sub
End Class
```

Then compile it and copy the DLL and PDB file to your SQL Server machine and run the following command in SQL Server:

```
CREATE ASSEMBLY CustomAggregate FROM '{path to your DLL}'
WITH PERMISSION_SET=SAFE;
GO

CREATE AGGREGATE Percentile(@value decimal(9, 3), @percentile int)
RETURNS decimal(9, 3) 
EXTERNAL NAME [CustomAggregate].[{namespace of your DLL}.Percentile];
GO
```

Answer (score -1):

I work for NHS as well here is the SQL whcih i wrote to find out median,MAX,and 95th percentile 
check this out and email me kali.tummala@gmail.com

```
WITH    kali1 ( k1, k2, k3, k4, k5, k6, k7 )
          AS ( SELECT   MinsInAE ,
                        HoursInAE ,
                        DaysInAE AS DaysInAE ,
                        Month_Name ,
                        YearName ,
                        InternalNo ,
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY Month_Name ORDER BY MinsInAE ASC ) AS 'Row Number'
               FROM     AE.FactAandE
                        INNER JOIN AE.PMI ON AE.FactAandE.FK_PaitentMasterIndex = AE.PMI.PK_Patient
                        INNER JOIN dbo.TimeDimension ON dbo.TimeDimension.DateId = AE.FactAandE.FK_date
               WHERE    YearName = 'Calendar 2010'
             ),
        kali2 ( k21, k22, k23 )
          AS ( SELECT   MAX(k7) * 95 / 100 ,
                        k4 ,
                        MAX(k7)
               FROM     kali1
               GROUP BY k4
             ),
        kali3 ( k31, k32 )
          AS ( SELECT   AVG(1.0E * MinsInAE) AS Median ,
                        Month_Name
               FROM     ( SELECT    MinsInAE ,
                                    Month_Name ,
                                    2
                                    * ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY Month_Name ORDER BY MinsInAE )
                                    - COUNT(*) OVER ( PARTITION BY Month_Name ) AS y
                          FROM      AE.FactAandE
                                    INNER JOIN AE.PMI ON AE.FactAandE.FK_PaitentMasterIndex = AE.PMI.PK_Patient
                                    INNER JOIN dbo.TimeDimension ON dbo.TimeDimension.DateId = AE.FactAandE.FK_date
                          WHERE     YearName = 'Calendar 2010'
                        ) AS d
               WHERE    y BETWEEN 0 AND 2
               GROUP BY Month_Name
             ),
        kali4 ( k41, k42, k43, k44, k46, k47 )
          AS ( SELECT   MinsInAE ,
                        HoursInAE ,
                        DaysInAE AS DaysInAE ,
                        Month_Name ,
                        YearName ,
                        InternalNo
               FROM     AE.FactAandE
                        INNER JOIN AE.PMI ON AE.FactAandE.FK_PaitentMasterIndex = AE.PMI.PK_Patient
                        INNER JOIN dbo.TimeDimension ON dbo.TimeDimension.DateId = AE.FactAandE.FK_date
               WHERE    YearName = 'Calendar 2010'
             ),
        kali5 ( k51, k52, k53 )
          AS ( SELECT   kali2.k22 AS Month_Name ,
                        ( kali1.k1 ) AS percentilevalue ,
                        kali2.k21 AS percentilerow
               FROM     kali2
                        INNER JOIN kali1 ON kali1.k4 = kali2.k22
               WHERE    kali1.k7 = kali2.k21
             )
    SELECT  kali3.k31 AS Median ,
            kali3.k32 AS Month_Name ,
            MAX(kali4.k41) AS Max_Mins_In_AE ,
            SUM(kali4.k41) AS Mins_IN_AE ,
            kali5.k51 AS Month_Name ,
            kali5.k52 AS percentile
    FROM    kali3
            LEFT JOIN kali4 ON kali3.k32 = kali4.k44
            LEFT JOIN kali5 ON kali5.k51 = kali3.k32
    GROUP BY kali3.k31 ,
            kali3.k32 ,
            kali5.k51 ,
            kali5.k52
```